# only first list element appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently building an e-commerce site which of course has a add-to-basket section.

The products are stored in an object and I am trying to append each one to a div which, when expanded by clicking on the cart icon, shows all items which have been added to the basket.

I am going about this by associating each products add-to-cart button with an id to match its object name, and then I am accessing the rest of the properties to append its relative information. However, only one of the elements are appending - everything else that follows does not append.

```js
var topSellers = {
  xboxController: {
    name: "XBOX KEYPAD CONTROLLER",
    price: 13.99
  },

  svengraphHeadphones: {
    name: "Svengraph Headphones",
    price: 23.49
  },

  toshibaFlatScreen: {
    name: "Toshiba 24' Flat Screen TV",
    price: 129.99
  },

  toshibaFlatScreen: {
    name: "Toshiba 24' Flat Screen TV",
    price: 129.99
  },

  Twinmos: {
    name: "TwinMOS Tablet 8GB",
    price: 129.99
  },

  hpElite: {
    name: "HP Elite PC",
    price: 439.99
  },

  hpElite: {
    name: "HP Elite PC",
    price: 439.99
  },

  externalHardive: {
    name: "1TB EXternal hardrive",
    price: 54.49
  },

  podcastMicrophone: {
    name: "Podcast Microphone",
    price: 34.99
  },

  ps4Slim: {
    name: "PS4 SLIM CONSOLE",
    price: 229.99
  }
}

var cartIcon = document.getElementById("shoppingBasket");
var basketDiv = document.getElementById("basketContent");
var itemsInBasket = 0;
var addItem = document.querySelectorAll(".itemToBasket");


cartIcon.addEventListener("click", function() {
  $(basketDiv).fadeIn("fast");
});


for (var i = 0; i < addItem.length; i++) {
  addItem[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    itemsInBasket++;
    var currentItem = this.id;
    document.getElementById("itemsAmount").innerText = itemsInBasket;

    // creating and appending elements to appear in the basket content
    var ulElement = document.createElement("ul");
    var listElement = document.createElement("li");
    ulElement.className = "basketItems";
    basketDiv.appendChild(ulElement);
    listElement.innerText = topSellers[currentItem].price;
    ulElement.appendChild(listElement);
    listElement.innerText = topSellers[currentItem].name;
    ulElement.appendChild(listElement);
  })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">This Weeks Online Top Selling Range</h1>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center top-sellers">
      <div class="more-info">

        <span class="strong">Brand</span><br> Microsoft
        <br>

        <span class="strong">Compatibility</span><br> XBox One, XBox 360, PC<br>

        <span class="strong">Type</span><br> Gamepad
        <br>

        <span class="strong">Connectivity</span><br> Wireless
        <br>

        <span class="strong">Feature</span><br> With feedback & motion sensing

      </div>
      <div class="standard-info">
        <h4>XBOX KEYPAD CONTROLLER</h4>
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/top-sellers/p1.jpg">
        <span class="price center-block">&pound;13.99</span>
        <button class="btn-std itemToBasket center-block" id="xboxController"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add To Basket</button>
      </div>
      <button class="btn-std product-info center-block"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Product Info</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center top-sellers">
      <div class="more-info">

        <span class="strong">Cord Length</span><br> 1.2m
        <br>

        <span class="strong">Headband</span><br> Adjustable
        <br>

        <span class="strong">Jack</span><br> 3.5mm
        <br>

        <span class="strong">Connectivity</span><br> Wired & Bluetooth<br>

        <span class="strong">Ear Pieces</span><br> Leatherette

      </div>
      <div class="standard-info">
        <h4>Svengraph Headphones</h4>
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/top-sellers/p2.png">
        <span class="price center-block">&pound;23.49</span>
        <button class="btn-std itemToBasket center-block" id="svengraphHeadphones"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-shopping-cart">
    </i> Add To Basket</button>
      </div>
      <button class="btn-std product-info center-block"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Product Info</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center top-sellers">
      <div class="more-info">

        <span class="strong">Dimensions</span><br> 33.9 x 55.4 x 6.1<br>

        <span class="strong">Resolution</span><br> 720p HD Ready<br>

        <span class="strong">Screen Type</span><br> LED
        <br>

        <span class="strong">Stand Type</span><br> Pivot
        <br>

        <span class="strong">HDMI Input</span><br> 1 Socket

      </div>
      <div class="standard-info">
        <h4>Toshiba 24" Flat Screen TV</h4>
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/top-sellers/p3.png">
        <span class="price center-block">&pound;129.99</span>
        <button class="btn-std itemToBasket center-block" id="toshibaFlatScreen"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add To Basket</button>
      </div>
      <button class="btn-std product-info center-block"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Product Info</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center top-sellers">
      <div class="more-info">

        <span class="strong">screen TYPE</span><br> 7" IPS HD<br>

        <span class="strong">RAM</span><br> 1GB DDR3<br>

        <span class="strong">Operating System</span><br> Google Android 4.0<br>

        <span class="strong">Camera Megapixel</span><br> Front: 0.3 MP | Back: 2 MP<br>

        <span class="strong">Proportion</span><br> 16:9

      </div>
      <div class="standard-info">
        <h4>TwinMOS Tablet 8GB</h4>
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/top-sellers/p4.png">
        <span class="price center-block">&pound;129.99</span>
        <button class="btn-std itemToBasket center-block" id="Twinmos"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add To Basket</button>
      </div>
      <button class="btn-std product-info center-block"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Product Info</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- START OF SECOND-ROW TOP-SELLING PRODUCTS SECTION -->

<div class="row" id="top-selling">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3 text-center top-sellers">
      <div class="more-info">

        <span class="strong">Operating System</span><br> Windows 10<br>

        <span class="strong">processor</span><br> i7-7700 Quad-core<br>

        <span class="strong">memory</span><br> 128 GB SSD storage<br>

        <span class="strong">Connectivity</span><br> Wireless & Bluetooth<br>

        <span class="strong">speakers</span><br> Quad speakers by Bang & Olufsen

      </div>

      <div class="standard-info">
        <h4>HP ELITE PC</h4>
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/top-sellers/p5.png">
        <span class="price center-block">&pound;439.99</span>
        <button class="btn-std itemToBasket center-block" id="hpElite"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add To Basket</button>
      </div>
      <button class="btn-std product-info center-block"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Product Info</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center top-sellers">
      <div class="more-info">

        <span class="strong">Data Transfer Rate</span><br> 5,120 MB per second<br>

        <span class="strong">Item Dimensions</span><br> 7.9 x 11.9 x 1.5 cm<br>

        <span class="strong">Item Weight</span><br> 230 grams<br>

        <span class="strong">Hard Disk Speed</span><br> 5,400 rpm<br>

        <span class="strong">Model Year</span><br> 2014

      </div>
      <div class="standard-info">
        <h4>1TB EXternal hardrive</h4>
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/top-sellers/p6.jpg">
        <span class="price center-block">&pound;54.49</span>
        <button class="btn-std itemToBasket center-block" id="externalHardive"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add To Basket</button>
      </div>
      <button class="btn-std product-info center-block"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Product Info</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center top-sellers">
      <div class="more-info">

        <span class="strong">Sensitivity</span><br> -55dB +2dB<br>

        <span class="strong">Directivity</span><br> Noise Cancelling<br>

        <span class="strong">Cord Length</span><br> Approx. 2m<br>

        <span class="strong">Operation Voltage</span><br> 1.5
        <br>

        <span class="strong">Frequency Response</span><br> 50Hz -16KHz

      </div>
      <div class="standard-info">
        <h4>podcast microphone</h4>
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/top-sellers/p7.jpg"> <span class="price center-block">&pound;34.99</span>
        <button class="btn-std itemToBasket center-block" id="podcastMicrophone"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add To Basket</button>
      </div>
      <button class="btn-std product-info center-block"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Product Info</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 text-center top-sellers">
      <div class="more-info">

        <span class="strong">Memory</span><br> 8GB GDDR5 <br>

        <span class="strong">Storage Size</span><br> 500GB, 5200 RPM<br>

        <span class="strong">dimensions</span><br> Approx. 275 x 53 x 305 mm<br>

        <span class="strong">Input/Output</span><br> Super-Speed USBx (USB 3.0)<br>

        <span class="strong">Networking</span><br> Ethernet x1 IEEE 802.11b/g/n

      </div>
      <div class="standard-info">
        <h4>PS4 SLIM CONSOLE</h4>

        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/top-sellers/p8.JPG"> <span class="price center-block">&pound;229.99</span> <button class="btn-std itemToBasket center-block" id="ps4Slim"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add To Basket</button>
      </div>
      <button class="btn-std product-info center-block"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> Product Info</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="shoppingBasket"></div>
```

Comment: Please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve :-)

Comment: Seems that it's working.. Another thing, if you are using jQuery, use it also for appending the list..